# Save a case class in Scala to a text file and recreate it without any modification to the case class

Tags: scala, case-class

How do I save a case class in my source code?

Background:

I am supposed to write a test for a mapper I wrote. Yet, my mapper gets a case class handed which has a list of hundreds of objects of another case classes as one of its attributes.

My Approach:

I would add Serializable Decorator to it as I read it described here: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-serialization-in-scala-serializable-trait

My Problem:

I don't have access to the case classes source. It's in a different file that I have imported.

Second Approach:

I tried to use unapply on the class, I got a long option string (About 23000 characters).

Problem, I can't turn it back to a class, mostly because as a written down string, it doesn't have quotation marks around the strings.

Has anyone a better method? Because if nothing helps, I will need to have to write my own class that can serialize, take on a string and map it back to the original case class. But since I am fairly new to Scala, I hope that that would be going overboard and Scala has a simple prebuild solution for this.

EDIT:
Oh yes, I can't just add more dependencies, because it is not my project. Therefore I am looking for a standard function. (I am right now working on the "myOwnCaseClass" approach. It looks like it might be less work than I have expected above. But we'll see.

Comment: You might try writing it as json using something like json4s.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention. I can't just add dependencies. Standard Library only. It's kind of a project in my internship. I will update my question with this information.

Comment: Do you want to serialize some specific case class? Or do you need to handle a general case? In general case you can serialize not all classes. Imagine if your class has a field of type `Thread`. How can it be serialized? Using some standard serialization library such as JSON serialization with external configuration (json4s, circe, play-json) might be a good idea. Or you might roll out your custom serialization basing on ideas in those libraries.

Comment: `case class`es are inherently `Serializable` (as long as its contents are). Would Java serialization format be acceptable?

Comment: @stefanobaghino for that I have to add the decorator, don't I? And therefore I face the same problem.

Comment: @SergGr I will try that, but for that, I still have to write the other case class to translate, don't I?

Comment: @SomeStranger314 Why a decorator?

Comment: @SomeStranger314, no. Typical Scala JSON library creates a [type class](https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html) for "serializable" classes and then you have to provide an "evidence" i.e. create an _object_ of the typeclass specialized for given class with implementation of the serialization. Production-grade JSON libraries also use macros to simplify generating such evidence objects. In the real world you should use some of the established libraries. For a exercise code you may go without macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Java serialization format is acceptable, you can leverage it for your purpose (`case class`es are inherently `Serializable`). Here are a few lines as an example (just change the path and you'll be able to copy and paste it to a Scala shell to see it running):

```
import java.io._

case class Foo(id: Long, name: Option[String])

val path = ??? // Write your path here

val fooToWrite = Foo(2L, None)
val out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path))
out.writeObject(fooToWrite)
out.close()

val in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path))
val fooToRead = in.readObject()
in.close()      

assert(fooToWrite == fooToRead)
```

Comment: I am trying this right now. Might take a while. I am running into issues not related to this, but probably to the idea. Like error messages that it doesn't let me read. But I will be back with stories of my success or peril :)

Comment: Short update. Repl says your code works fine. Integrated into my specific case class, it throws a ClassNotFoundException. I will try again tomorrow. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you a lot.